# includable header/nav linking path problems

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, path, directory

I have made an includable header with a new-bar inside. But I am stuck linking files in the menu on different pages except for index.php. I know it is a directory/path problem. That's the link does not recognize the path. But how can I find a way to make the new work on different directory levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for getting document root directory and then do something like:

```
$navbar = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/menu.php';
include_once $navbar;
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is defined in your server settings. For most server it is defined and you are good to go.

another solution is to use: `realpath(dirname(__file__))`